# How to autosizing TextWidget in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to set auto-size to `TextWidget` in Flutter.

It's like
Autosizing TextViews | Android Developers https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/autosizing-textview.html

Does Flutter support it?
How to implement auto-sizing `TextWidge`t?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can puy your TextWidget inside [Fexible Widget](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Flexible-class.html). Flexible Widget automatically gives it's child the available space.

Comment: But if we give a text size of like 1000 then it overflows the Expanded widget, which simply ruins the purpose of `AutoResizeTextView`

Answer (score 2):

I could implement it using [FittedBox](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/FittedBox/FittedBox.html).

```
new FittedBox(
    fit: BoxFit.contain,
    child: new Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: new Text(
            'LooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooongText',
        ),
    ),
),
```